# Cambiar valor a variable con click a botón

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alguien por favor me puede explicar por que no se ejecuta cuando doy click en el botón, solo entra en el `else` lo cual esta correcto, pero en teoría al dar click al botón `btn_limpiar_hora_extra` debería cambiar el valor de la variable a `true` y ejecutar la condición. Gracias.

```js
var ejecutar = false;
$("#btn_limpiar_hora_extra").click(function() {
  ejecutar = true;
});
if (ejecutar) {
  alert("clicked");
} else {
  alert("no´t clicked");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="button" id="btn_limpiar_hora_extra" name="btn_limpiar_hora_extra" value="Enviar" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se debe a que no tienes el código dentro de la función `click`, si das click asignarás el valor `true` a la variable `ejecutar`, pero no podrás ejecutar el `alert` debido a que no lo estás llamando dentro de la función, solo se ejecuta cuando cargas la página debido a que desde un principio tiene el valor `false` y se manda a llamar la condición `if`, y como inicia con un valor `false` te ejecuta el `else`. Si presionas el botón estarás asignando `true` y nada más:

Código modificado:

```js
var ejecutar = false;
$("#btn_limpiar_hora_extra").click(function() {
  ejecutar = true;
  if (ejecutar) {
  alert("clicked");
} else {
  alert("no´t clicked");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="button" id="btn_limpiar_hora_extra" name="btn_limpiar_hora_extra" value="Enviar" />
```

Espero te ayude. Cualquier duda pregunta sin problemas. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias así funciono perfectamente. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto compañero, espero hayas entendido lo que se explica en la respuesta. Saludos y suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner el código dentro del evento click:

```js
var ejecutar = false;
$("#btn_limpiar_hora_extra").click(function() {
    ejecutar = true;
    if (ejecutar) {
        alert("clicked");
    } else {
        alert("no´t clicked");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="button" id="btn_limpiar_hora_extra" name="btn_limpiar_hora_extra" value="Enviar" />
```

El cambio de la variable no se hace hasta que hayas hecho el click, por ende, el if debe ir luego de este cambio.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ejecutar = false;
//evento del boton
$("#btn_limpiar_hora_extra").click(function() {
  ejecutar = true;
});
//funcion para validar si ya se hizo click o no
function validar(){
if (ejecutar) {
  alert("clicked");
} else {
  alert("no´t clicked");
}
//reinicio la variable
ejecutar = false;
}

//para probar esto hay dos formas.
//si das clic en el boton y luego llamas a validar, debe aparecer el alert de "clicked".
//pero si llamas a validar primero debe salir el alert "no´t clicked"
```